# 作为此 Grammar Purpose

Tags: grammar

What is the purpose of `作为此` in this [sentence](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/extending/index.html):

```
本指南仅介绍了作为此 CPython 版本的一部分提供的创建扩展的基本工具
```

It is translated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) as

```
This guide only covers the basic tools for creating extensions provided as part of this version of CPython.
```

So I guess it means something akin to `as` in English. Would `作为` also work or is `作为此` required?

Is there an alternative way of wording this sentence to not use `作为此`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have slightly misparsed the syntax of the statement.

Let us put some spacing and some brackets around the largest blocks:

> 本指南 仅 介绍了 [ 作为 此CPython版本 的 一部分 提供 的 创建 扩展 的 ] 基本工具

We can see that `此` modifies `CPython 版本` and does not "belong to" 作为.

Answer (score 1):

Pre- translate:
本指南仅介绍了作为此 CPython 版本的一部分
This guide only introduces as/for this CPython version 的 part

提供的创建扩展的基本工具。
provide 的 found/establish/create extend/extension 的 basic tool

Translate:
本指南仅介绍了作为此 CPython 版本的一部分提供的创建扩展的基本工具
This guide covers only the basic tools for creating extensions that are provided as part of this CPython release.

作为 = for
此 = this
作为此 CPython 版本
for this version of CPython